# Trying to write to an outfile.txt using variables from an if block

Tags: java

I am trying to write to an outfile.txt using variables that are inside `if` statements.

when I compile it it keeps saying the variable has not been initialized when in fact they have been, one as a string and char as the other.

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class program5{
    // read string keyboard inputs
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        // read string keyboard inputs
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int i, gradeA_count = 0, gradeB_count = 0, gradeC_count = 0, 
                gradeD_count = 0, gradeF_count = 0, first_grade, 
                second_grade, third_grade, fourth_grade, 
                total_of_grades;

        String remarks, course_name, semester, instructor_name, student_name;
        char grade;
        double average_grade;
        int[] array_of_int_numbers = new int[10];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // set up a outfile to write to
        Writer outfile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("e:outfile.txt")); 
        // Write the class information to the outfile
        outfile.write("               CMPS 161 Program Five, Fall 2015\n\n"); 
        // separate top and next line for ease of sight
        outfile.write("               -------------------------------- \n\n");
        System.out.println("Enter the course name: ");

        course_name=input.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the Semester: ");
        semester=input.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the Instructor: ");
        instructor_name=input.readLine();
        outfile.write("Course: " +(String.format("%-8s",course_name))+ "      Semester: " +(String.format("%-10s",semester))+ "      Instructor: " +(String.format("%-12s",instructor_name))+ "\n\n");
        outfile.write("Array Item Student Name            T1 T2 T3 T4  Avg Grade Remarks\n\n");
        outfile.write("=================================================================\n\n");

        // array initialization
        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) array_of_int_numbers[i] = 0;

        // prompt user for a value into the array
        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter a Students Name: ");
            student_name=input.readLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the first grade: ");
            first_grade=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the second grade: ");
            second_grade=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the third grade: ");
            third_grade=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the fourth grade: ");
            fourth_grade=sc.nextInt();
            total_of_grades = first_grade + second_grade + third_grade + fourth_grade;
            average_grade = (double) total_of_grades / 4.0;
            System.out.println("Your average grade is " +(String.format("%.1f",average_grade))+ "\n");

            if (average_grade >= 90){
                remarks = "Excellent";
                grade = 'A';
                gradeA_count++;
            }else if (average_grade >= 80){
                remarks = "Very Good";
                grade = 'B';
                gradeB_count++;
            }else if (average_grade >= 70){
                remarks = "Good";
                grade = 'C';
                gradeC_count++;
            }else if (average_grade >= 60){
                remarks = "Poor";
                grade = 'D';
                gradeD_count++;
            }else if (average_grade >= 0){
                remarks = "Fail";
                grade = 'F';
                gradeF_count++;
            }

            outfile.write("["+i+"]"+ student_name +
                                "" + first_grade +
                                "" + second_grade +
                                "" + third_grade +
                                ""+ fourth_grade +
                                "%" + average_grade +
                                "" + grade +
                                "" + remarks + "\n");
        }

        for (i = 0; i < array_of_int_numbers.length; i++){
            System.out.println("array_of_int_numbers["+(i+1)+ "] = "+array_of_int_numbers[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Number of A's : " + gradeA_count);
        System.out.println("Number of B's : " + gradeB_count);
        System.out.println("Number of C's : " + gradeC_count);
        System.out.println("Number of D's : " + gradeD_count);
        System.out.println("Number of F's : " + gradeF_count);
        outfile.close();
    } // end program

} // end class
```

I am new to coding (only my fifth program) and this is my first semester in college, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using JGrasp as my professor requires it and coding in java.

Edit:
Here are the exceptions being thrown:

```
program5.java:107: error: variable grade might not have been initialized
                                "" + grade +
                                     ^
program5.java:108: error: variable remarks might not have been initialized
                                "" + remarks + "\n");
                                     ^
```

Comment: Which variables aren't initialized?  Declaration and initialization are different things.  Including the variable declarations and (if done separately) initialization code, plus the block in which the exception is being thrown in addition to your pastebin would be helpful.

Comment: Please, please, please take a look http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html it is an old article but STILL valid. Also, your indentarion was terrible, in the same provided link there are a section to it!! Take a good read! Compare your code now with the one you provided, see how it should be formatted!

Comment: Hint: what value has `grade` (or `remarks`) when `average_grade` is negative

Comment: My bad, I forgot to say it.  The variables are remarks and grade  program5.java:98: error: variable grade might not have been initialized
                                "" + grade +
                                     ^
program5.java:99: error: variable remarks might not have been initialized
                                "" + remarks + "\n");

Comment: Edited the post with the exceptions being thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of the program, when you declare `grade` and `remarks`, you aren't initializing it. You must set these variables to a default value.

For example:

```
String remarks = "";
char grade = '0';
```

It doesn't really matter what they're set to right now, because they'll be changed later.

Now, if you know that `average_grade` will never be negative, then you can replace that last `else if` statement with a simple `else`. This is why Java thinks that the variables may not be initialized, because there is the possibility that `average_grade` could become negative.

Comment: It would be great if you explain OP about the WHY is he receiving this error since he "used" these variables on his IF conditions. As @RC pointed out in his comment. Just so you know, I know why, I just think that OP should also know!

Comment: Edited. Should be enough explanation.

Comment: Tenny, Thank you for the answer!  I have no idea why I did not think of that since my gradeA_count things do it!  Thank you very much

Comment: @BH12 consider in accepting the answer if it is right. Click on the "V" on the right side of the answer below the 0. And if you want to give more points to the answer you can upvote it by clicking on the up triangle.